# BFS - TypeError: 'ellipsis' object is not subscriptable - implementing algorithm

Tags: python

I am trying to implement the BFS algorithm but python is giving me an error that the ellipsis object is not sub scriptable.

I am unsure what these means because as far as I am aware this type should not be Ellipsis?

```
TypeError: 'ellipsis' object is not subscriptable
```

Causing error:

```
visited[starting_row][starting_col] = True
```

Function:

```
def findRoute(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):

    grid = self.grid
    print(grid)

    starting_row, starting_col = x1, y1

    # Creating 2 seperate queues for X and Y.
    x_queue, y_queue = deque(), deque()

    number_of_moves = 0

    number_of_nodes_in_current_layer = 1
    number_of_nodes_in_next_layer = 0

    end_reached = False

    # Up/Down/Right/Left directions
    direction_row = [-1, 1, 0, 0]
    direction_col = [0, 0, 1, -1]

    visited = ...
    x_queue.append(starting_row)
    y_queue.append(starting_col)
    visited[starting_row][starting_col] = True
    while len(x_queue) > 0:
        x = x_queue.dequeue()
        y = y_queue.dequeue()

        if x == x2 & y == y2:
            end_reached = True
            break

        # for(i = 0; i < 4; i++):
        # Loop through direction.
        for i in range(0, 4):
            new_row = x + direction_row[i]
            new_col = x + direction_col[i]

        #Validate position
        # Skip locations not in grid.
        if new_row < 0 or new_col < 0 or new_row >= self.height or new_col >= self.width:
            continue

        # Skip locations already visited / cells blocked by walls.
        if visited[new_row][new_col] or grid[new_row][new_col]:
            continue

        x_queue.enqueue(new_row)
        y_queue.enqueue(new_col)
        visited[new_row][new_col] = True
        number_of_nodes_in_next_layer += 1

        if number_of_nodes_in_current_layer == 0:
            number_of_nodes_in_current_layer = number_of_nodes_in_next_layer
            number_of_nodes_in_next_layer = 0
            number_of_moves += 1
        if end_reached:
            return number_of_moves
        return -1

    return grid[1][2]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has this line:

```
visited = ...
```

This `...` is not commonly used, but it is a native object. The documentation on [`Ellipsis`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) has:

> The same as the ellipsis literal “`...`”. Special value used mostly in conjunction with extended slicing syntax for user-defined container data types. `Ellipsis` is the sole instance of the `types.EllipsisType` type.

As the error message states, this object is not subscriptable, yet that is exactly what you tried to do with:

```
visited[starting_row][starting_col] = True
```

I suppose you didn't really intend to use `visited = ...`, and that you were planning to complete this statement later and then forgot about it. It should be:

```
visited = [[False] * len(row) for row in grid]
```